# Upload Image to Firebase Storage with the current users UID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

How do you upload an image that will also have the current user's UID attached?

Example below.
[image]

This is the code I am using to upload the image, but so far having no success adding on the UID.

```
private void updloadImage(Uri pickedImage){
        StorageReference myStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("users_photos");
        final StorageReference imagePath = myStorage.child(pickedImage.getLastPathSegment());
        userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        imagePath.putFile(pickedImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                imagePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        UserProfileChangeRequest myUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setPhotoUri(uri).build();


                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: What exactly does it mean for you to "attach" a UID to a file?  What are you planning to do with that UID once it's attached in the way that you're thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user's UID to be part of the image file name in Cloud Storage, you'd do:

```
StorageReference myStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("users_photos");
final StorageReference imagePath = myStorage.child(pickedImage.getLastPathSegment());
userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
imagePath.putFile(userID+"_"+pickedImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
```

If you instead want the image(s) for a user to end up in a subfolder based on their UID, you'd change that last line to:

```
imagePath.child(userID).putFile(pickedImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
```

Comment: How about having the images put just in the "users_photos" folder and then setting the name of the image as UID. How would I go around doing that?

Comment: That'd be `imagePath.child("users_photos").putFile(userID)`.