# Get userId inside firebase storage trigger

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

How to get uid of the authenticated user from the storage trigger below:

```
exports.storageSizeCounter = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object, context) => {...});
```

*auth/uid* is available during security rule evaluation but it seems like it's not passed to the trigger (like in `context.auth`).

Any way to get the uid inside the storage trigger?

Comment: That trigger doesn't have context available, you don't have access to the user uid on that function https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions

Comment: As andresmijares commented, the user information is not available by default. If you need it, the common approach is to pass the UID as part of the path or in the metadata, and then use security rules to ensure it is correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60460257, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58827666